# MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench"

Tags: eclipse

For no reason I am getting Failed to create the part's controls and in error log it gives java.lang.NullPointerException. I am using eclipse neon and the debug was with issues till I modify some thing in run/debug. After this changes the issues keep popping up for all the java application.

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2018-10-25 13:31:52.572
>   !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a scala IDE installed in eclipse. I uninstalled that plugin and this resolved the issue for me.